# Jenkins - Run windows BAT to start Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, jenkins, conda

I have a Jenkins windows setup installed on Windows 10 machine.
I would like to schedule a building that simply execute a BAT file which is aimed to run a script on Anaconda Virtual Env:

```
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
call cd C:\tensorflow1\Projects\dcp\m3u\m3u_parser
call conda activate tensorflow1
```

When I try to run it I got this error

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\txx
[txx] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins401597951051427948.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\txx>call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

(base) C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\txx>call cd C:\tensorflow1\Projects\dcp\m3u\m3u_parser

(base) C:\tensorflow1\Projects\dcp\m3u\m3u_parser>call conda activate tensorflow1
Could not find conda environment: tensorflow1
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.


(base) C:\tensorflow1\Projects\dcp\m3u\m3u_parser>exit 1
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I run BAT from windows I can execute with no issue.
What am I doing wrong?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Jenkins is running with a different user account than the one that owns your Anaconda environments?

```
Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
```

If you're sure that Jenkins can access the conda environments, then use the full pathname to your environment folder, rather than just the name of the environment. The Jenkins user might not share the name-to-folder mapping that your regular user has.